# wrong date showing up in front end from AWS RDS postgres DB

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-rds

I am developing an application running with Angular 5 + spring boot.The tst environment in deployed in AWS and the DB is AWD RDS. The data saved in the date column is not showing correctly in my UI. Example, data saved in the date column is '2018-08-18' But in front end it shows 'August, 17, 2018'. But no issues in my local environment with the same data. Date is showing up correctly in local.
I modified the timezone in AWS server using `sudo timedatectl set-timezone America/New_York` and in RDS using `SET TIMEZONE='America/New_York';` Also changed timezone inside the docker container using `docker run -e TZ=America/New_York debian:jessie date`
But still it is not showing up correctly. Do I have to restart the server ?
Any pointers will be of great help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute 
`SET TIME ZONE 'America/New_York';`
every time you connect.
This query is only applied to the current connection.

You can check the current timezone by issuing

`SELECT * FROM pg_settings WHERE name='TimeZone'`;